# compromised の日本語訳は？

Tags: security, 英語

https://security.stackexchange.com/ などセキュリティ系の情報を読んでいると、しきりに compromised という単語が出てきますが、(例: compromised hardware, compromised OS, etc) compromise された状態とはどういう状態でしょうか。また、日本語に訳すとしたら何になりますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- （クラッカーなどに）侵入された
- （ウィルスなどに）感染した

という意味ではないでしょうか。
[英辞郎](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%22compromised%22)などには「易感染性」のような意味も出ていますから、医学用語由来かもしれませんね。
易感染性という言葉から類推すると、脆弱なだけでまだ侵入されていない場合にも使うのかもしれません。

しかし少なくとも、「侵入された可能性がかなりある」くらいにはマズい状況に使われている気がします。

---

OP 追記: 医学用語における易感染性とは、免疫が落ちて通常なんでもない微生物にでも感染してしまう状態です。そのような状態に陥ってしまった患者のことを compomised host と呼びます。

なので、ウイルス、クラッカーに侵入された(可能性がある)状態に陥ってしまった、 が一番適切な翻訳だと思われます。

Comment: 一番適切な説明はこれであるような気がするので accept します。

Answer (score 2):

「何らか原因によって危険に晒されている状態」、ではないですか？
暴露しているという意味合いが強い気がします。

Answer (score 1):

直訳すると"妥協したハードウェア"、"妥協したOS",,,ということから転じて、危うい○○、の意味があるようです。セキュリティ界隈では使われているとのこと。

http://eigo-1-1.blogspot.jp/2012/11/compromise-compromise.html
http://hmbdyh.hatenablog.com/entry/20130509/1368095425

Answer (score 1):

`危うい～～`
も確かに使われる時もあるかと思いますが
`risk of compromised`
となるとその訳に疑問が出てしまいますね。

[ここ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30736/a-data-compromise)でも語られていますが
動詞と名詞で用法と意味が違うと思います。

"compromised"が動詞で使われる訳として
(セキュリティなどを)"破る"・"壊す"・"崩す"などの意味合いで使われることがあります。
(mjyさんも言われているように"侵入・感染"と言った意味でも使われることもあるようです)

名詞としては確かに"妥協"と言った意味合いも持っていますが、
セキュリティ的な意味合いでは"compromised"よりも

- breach
- penetration
- exploit

を使用したほうがネイティブぽい（？）かもしれません。

他では"脆弱性"と言った意味で使われていることも見たことはありますが……